# Unable to parse an image link from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape two images from two identical links using requests. However, the script that I've created can't grab them. Although the image link is generated dynamically, most of the times there are ways to parse that using requests. So, I tried to find it using dev tools but failed. To let you know, this is the location of [the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9O1D2.jpg) which is taken from the first link.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

links = [
    'https://www.glideapps.com/templates/baby-reveal-boy-or-girl-wr',
    'https://www.glideapps.com/templates/escool-virtual-school-6d'
]

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    for link in links:
        res = s.get(link)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')
        app_image = soup.select_one("img.h-full")['src']
        print(app_image)
```

PS Selenium is not an option I would like to go with.

Comment: please explicitly specify expected behavior and actual behavior in the question, what errors you face if any when running the code

Comment: Maybe I've misunderstood your intention, but are you trying to steal higher resolution images from glideapps.com ?

Comment: Check out the edit @Grysik. Btw, resolution doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession


links = [
    'https://www.glideapps.com/templates/baby-reveal-boy-or-girl-wr',
    'https://www.glideapps.com/templates/escool-virtual-school-6d'
]

def main():
    with HTMLSession() as session:
        for link in links:
            res = session.get(link)
            res.raise_for_status()
            res.html.render()
            for img in res.html.xpath('//*/img[contains(@class, "h-full")]'):
                print(img.attrs['src'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```